# Using a routine defined in a Fortran module to find a library with AC_SEARCH_LIBS (autoconf)

Tags: fortran, shared-libraries, autotools, autoconf

Consider you have a module

```
module bingo
  contains
    subroutine blah()
    end subroutine blah
end module bingo
```

in the file called *bingo.f90*.

Lets say you made a shared library libbingo.so from bingo.f90

Now, if your program uses *libbingo*, in the *configure.ac* one *could* write something like

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([blah],[bingo],,[AC_MSG_WARN(bingo not found)])
```

to check for the existence of *libbingo* in the searchable system paths, or LDFLAGS env. variable. Macro AC_SEARCH_LIBS produces a super-simple code snippet containing a call to blah, to make sure we're using the right library.

**The problem is, this is not working for functions that reside within Fortran modules.** The reason why it does not work is that the test code snippet produced by AC_SEARCH_LIBS contains only a statement `call blah()`  while the actual name in the library object is probably mangled beyond recognition. In fact, the output of *nm* command applied to the library file gives something of the form *__bingo_MOD_blah* as the actual routine name (when *bingo.f90* is compiled with gfortran ver. 5; I don't know how compiler-specific these names are).

My solution so far is to artificially add a subroutine outside of a module definition, an *external subprogram*, and use this to identify the library. In other words, *bingo.f90* becomes

```
module bingo
  contains
    subroutine blah()
    end subroutine blah
end module bingo
subroutine autoconfhook()
end subroutine autoconfhook !.
```

The generated *configure* script will correctly find *libbingo* if the following macro is used

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([autoconfhook],[bingo],,[AC_MSG_WARN(bingo not found)]) #.
```

As I said, this works, but I would love to know if there is an approach to  identify a library by a routine independently of it residing in a module, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid for this you should rely on `AC_LINK_IFELSE` and write the logic yourself.

Since `AC_LINK_IFELSE` allows you to select the language, you should be able to write your small snippets of Fortran that looks for the function within the module.

Comment: That's what i was afraid of. But, if someone has already a test like that already baked, would be nice to share.

Comment: `AX_F90_LIBRARY` on [the Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_f90_library.html#ax_f90_library) is the closest I can find. I'd suggest if you don't want to keep a snowflake around (and I praise you for that!), that the best would be to contribute a new macro to the archive, like `AX_F90_SEARCH_LIB`.